# Multiple voucher codes on 1 DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have 1 data extension, with 4 sets of unique voucher codes. Each set has 5k vouchers (so 20k all together), and there is a voucher code type next to each unique code. e.g. 10% off, 20% off, 30% off and 40% off. I know that this can be done in 4 different DE, but I wanted to know if it's possible to have them all in one DE, and then somehow use the claim row function, or any function to only allocate the correct voucher code type. The incoming data will be stamped with which discount voucher codes needs to be use.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: As long as each of the voucher codes are unique across each of the 4 different sets, then the claimrow() function should work according to the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can’t have a condition within the ClaimRow function. I have been facing same use case, and after consulting Salesforce, I saw no other options than utilising separate DEs, one for each type of code/discount.

Comment: Thanks Lukas - I thought so. Spent hours trying to figure it out, and then in the end went with the different DE per voucher code type option

Comment: I will suggest reaching out to SF, so they can add this to their product roadmap - as this is something they are quite open to. If enough requests are made around same features, they might actually be implemented.

Comment: Great - will do. Is this via a case?

Comment: Or reach out to your account executive